# In October CMS, how can I make an image editable in a Static Page?

Tags: plugins, static-pages, octobercms

I'd like to set up a generic marketing template using the October CMS "Static Pages" plug-in.  The intention is to allow my clients to create their own marketing pages.  Let's assume that my layout contains HTML similar to this:

```
<img src="/path/to/image.jpg">
<hr>
<p>Some uneditable copy</p>

{% placeholder copy default title="Main Page Copy" type="html" %}
  <h1>Some Awesome Headline</h1>
  <p>Sea no omnium deserunt, eum tale movet sensibus te.</p>
{% endplaceholder %}
```

How could I allow my clients to change the image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a full explenation here
https://octobercms.com/blog/post/building-client-friendly-websites

Add this code to your layout

```
{variable name="banner" label="Banner" tab="Header" type="mediafinder" mode="image"}{/variable}
```

and this into your html markup

```
<img src="{{ banner|media }}" alt="" />
```

You will see the extra field in your backend

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be currently supported: https://github.com/rainlab/pages-plugin/issues/13, but maybe you can use the [media manager](https://github.com/rainlab/pages-plugin/issues/7#issuecomment-112479065)